# .NET Service reference sending wrong accept header (text/plain)

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, service-reference, content-negotiation

I've created an ASP.NET Core web application, and installed + used the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version `6.1.5` Nuget package. This hosts the [following openapi document](https://mintplayer.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json) on `https://example.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json`.

Also my API supports content-negotiation.

- When sending no `Accept` header, or `Accept: text/xml` header, the api will return an XML string
- When sending an `Accept: application/json` header, the api will return a JSON string

Now I've tried consuming my api through the swagger document:

- Create a new .NET Core console application
- Right-click the project file → Add → Service Reference
- OpenAPI

  - URL: [https://example.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json](https://mintplayer.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json)
  - Namespace: Example.Api
  - Class name: ExampleClient

You can then write a `Main` like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    // httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var mintPlayerClient = new MintPlayer.Api.MintPlayerClient("https://mintplayer.com", httpClient);
    var artists = await mintPlayerClient.ApiArtistListAsync(false);
}
```

Now when you debug the console app

- navigate to the `ApiArtistListAsync` method in the `swaggerClient` class
- put a breakpoint at the `client_.SendAsync` call
- you can now inspect what the swaggerClient is sending to the webservice

[image: .NET Swagger Client is sending an Accept:text/plain header]

Usually it's like this:

- SOAP = XML
- REST = JSON

Even when adding a `DefaultRequestHeader` on the `HttpClient` the response from the HttpClient is an XML, because it's explicitly added inside the SwaggerClient method:

[image: A text/plain header is explicitly added to the request]

And here is how the code is generated + the line where the Accept header is explicitly set (`swaggerClient:430`). This is auto-generated code from adding the service-reference.

[image: How I added the service reference]

So why is the Accept header in the generated code explicitly set to `text/plain`? Why isn't the default accept header value `application/json`, since this is a REST service?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to check this on both side, client(your console) and server(your api project).

We all know that usually

- SOAP = XML
- REST = JSON

But you're coding the whole things, total in-control of what being send and what being response.

Let's assume you client send Accept-Header which support both `text/xml` and `text/plain` (which as i understand here, you expect a response as `text/plain`).

Then the server realize that your console is happy with either `text/xml` and `text/plain`, and the server itself support all kind of common format.

So it'll have to electing the most convenient format to response to the client.
Which in this case is `text/xml`.
That's so, the console received and happy with `text/xml` response format either way

And if that's the case, that I get you right, you want to receive `text/plain` on the console, then make sure the only `Accept` header sending out is `text/plain` or do some custom logic on your API to choose the `text/plain` format over others when sending response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I don't seem to have control over the `Accept` header that's being sent by the generated `xxxClient`. As you say I can always handle `text/plain` the same as `application/json`, but it seems kinda "hacky". Still wondering however why the generated client would forcefully overwrite the `Accept` header

Comment: [Something like this](https://finisky.github.io/2020/09/06/aspnetcoresupporttextplain.en/)

Comment: I believe they're not overiding anything... as i just made a test and capture the result for you. First, on my [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB7IK.png), then my [api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCU4w.png), then the [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBVJ.png). The response was `application/json` here only cause i don't register a serializer for `text/plain` on the server, also not customize the response type election process. 
But the point here is... the client doesn't forcefully overwrite the `Accept` header, she's loyal to you.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I updated my question a little. The api works fine, but the problem is that, when adding the service reference to the `swagger.json`, the code generation seems to explicitly add an instruction which sets the `Accept` header to `text/plain` (as in the GIF), which doesn't make sence to me...

Comment: @Pieterjan you might want to check the auto-generate API file again, i just came across your swagger file and spot out `/api/v1/Artist` api response with `text/plain` on the top most format option... If i was right, the `Accept` header of the auto generate file choose the top most option to generate that header. (and again, it's not override, just add another accept option!)

Comment: Good point. It seems as if the order of the Accept is determined by the order of the MvcOptions.OutputFormatters which carry the SupportedMediaTypes

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need "plain/text" output format, you can remove "plain/text" output formatter using :

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
})
```